# Convolutional Neural Network nonlinearity understanding

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, nonlinear-regression, supervised-learning

In convolutional neural networks, we apply filters to an input image and get a feature map. Then we apply a nonlinearity function ReLu. I am not sure I understand what the nonlinearity function is applied on. Is it applied to each of the entries on the feature map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

That's what going on in the filter of a convolutional neural net. It forces weights to be equal, hence the common colors going to each neuron in the hidden layer on the right, and it drops (sets to zero) some of the weights. In contrast, a fully-connected layer would have a unique color per pixel-neuron pairing, meaning $9\times 4=36$ colors, rather than the four used here.

(There is a unique bias term for each neuron in that layer to the right, but I have omitted those, lest the picture get too cluttered and require eight colors.)

The nonlinearity happens in the neurons on the hidden layers (and often the output layer), the same as it would for a fully-connected layer.

Comment: A good exercise might be to figure out how my drawing corresponds to the way you known CNNs as having a little square on top of a bigger square. As a hint, I am using one $2\times 2$ filter. (It was cool for me to slug through this one day, figure out what's happening when I put a couple of filters over an image, check the number of parameters when I implemented it in Keras, and see it match what I worked out in my notebook.)