# CNN : Is the learning on Kernels in CNN done pixel by pixel or after each image

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network

i work with neural network but i am new in the field of CNN.
I have difficulties to understand the learning process at the Kernel level.

I understand that each kernel give each Layers and that this is the result of the convolution on the input image. But how the learning work in this context ?

For example : during a backpropagation the learning reach a kernel with, let's say, a positive feedback, if the learning use here a notion of activation of the inputs, at the level of a kernel, it needs to apply on one of the inputs that have been convolved by the kernel. But at this point i imagine that the convolution have already been processed on the global image, so what are the input used ?

Thanks for the answers ;)

**Edit :**
The link to *« Convolutional Neural Network nonlinearity understanding »* send by Dave answer only partially to the question because it illustrate the fact that there is weight sharing, and so, it illustrate one aspect of the question (the kernel which learn with the same weights but for different input/output couple) without explaining HOW the weights sharing is done in practice. Which is the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convolutional Neural Network nonlinearity understanding](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/518602/convolutional-neural-network-nonlinearity-understanding) // A convolutional neural network just forces weights to be equal ("weight sharing") or forces weights to be zero. This gets lost when we think of CNNs as putting rectangles on top of bigger rectangles, but that's what's going on.

Comment: Ok, I imagine that it's logical when this is called « convolutionnal » :p with in fact one learning only by kernel, and the schematic help a bit but it is not my real question. To specify it : HOW the weights are forced to be equal here ? Is the learning done on one input then on another, with a little learning rate to « meld » the synapses changes for each input/output or is there another rule applied here ?

Comment: Set aside computer science issues like learning rate or any other aspect of how we get the parameters, and focus on a neural network as a regression equation with a loss function. Start by writing out the neural network corresponding to: $$f(x_1, x_2) = b_3 + w_5\text{ReLU}(b_1 + w_1x_1 + w_3x_2) + w_6\text{ReLU}(b_2 + w_2x_1 + w_4x_2)$$ Once you have that, decide that $w_5 = w_6$ and $w_1 = 0$. Do you see how this corresponds to dropping connections and duplicating colors in the picture in the link I gave?

Comment: I don't really see the correspondance. If i translate the CNN case, isn't it more like if i have many equations (so many outputs) with the same weight on each.
Like : 
f1(x1,x2)=b3+w5*x1+w6*x2
f2(x3,x4)=b3+w5*x3+w6*x4
with many output (for each kernel operation) and different inputs (when the kernel move) with the same weights shared. (with the inputs that can be the output of other layers on the form ReLU(...).

Comment: Besides, note that my question is specifically on the computer science side. I understand that the weight must be shared, but this could be done via many different implementation that will share the same result equation. Here my question is specifically on the implementation used to achieve the result.

Comment: In your edit, what do you mean by “HOW” the weight sharing is done?

Comment: How it is done technically. You have multiples inputs (the images) and multiples outputs (the filters) but with the same weigths shared. So the propagation of the gradient on these weigth is not natural. I can see several methods tgo achieve the result, but i don't know which one is done in practice in the most common implementations.
Some papers seems to says that this is a simple mean between all the different error gradient for each input/output couple, but this points is fuzzy.